# HTML - What are the most important accessibility features?

Tags: html, accessibility

What are the most important HTML tags for a visually impaired user when viewing a website?  It's something I feel I've neglected to cater for in all my years in development which I now feel bad about, so want to make an effort from this point onwards to make any information I serve up to a good standard of accessibility.

For example, alt tags on images is about as far as my knowledge extends.

Also as a side question, is a side effect of accessibility features better SEO?  As a web crawler is basically a visually impaired user as well.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/75526/285619

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"What are the most important HTML tags?" -- almost all of them. The majority of HTML tags have semantics associated with them which can be extremely useful to non-visual browsers; it is unfortunate that most websites hardly use these tags. You can find a complete list in the [HTML5 draft spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/), especially section 4.6 on text-level semantics -- most of these have existed since HTML 3 or 4, which is more than a decade now.

To point out the most interesting ones:

- `<abbr>` to mark abbreviations/acronyms (this is probably the only tag that is commonly used) -- this would tell the computer, for example, to spell out H-T-M-L and not try to pronounce it
- `<blockquote>` or `<q>` for text quoted from other sources
- `<dfn>` for a term that is being defined
- `<var>`, `<samp>` and `<kbd>` to mark various semantics of code snippets or input/output
- `<address>` for addresses and other contact information
- `<dl>`, `<dt>` and `<dd>` for lists of terms and definitions, such as a glossary

Also, most of the new tags in HTML5 have very specific uses, such as `<nav>` (page navigation that a screen reader could possibly skip), `<article>`, `<header>`, `<footer>` and `<time>`.

Answer (score 0):

- Alt text
- Special tags
- ARIA

These are the important ones. Article link below gives you more clear view. https://www.codecademy.com/articles/accessibility